# jQuery on 'blur' event not fired on Safari Radio button

Tags: jquery, safari

Simple `$(document).on('blur', 'td', function (e) {` not firing in Safari 14. Works on Chrome, Edge, Firefox.

```
console.log('running');
$(document).on('blur', 'td', function (e) { 
console.log('blurred td');
myClass = $(this).attr('class').replace(/\s.+$/, ''); 

if (myClass === "clock" || myClass === "sumCalc") { //if blurried RADIO buttons
                input = $(this).children('input').filter(":checked").attr('value');
                console.log(myClass);
                e.stopPropagation();
        }
    
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/atis_/12pfkeuy/15/
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like Safari won't focus on selected radio button when it is clicked.
So I had to add this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input:radio', function(e) {
$(this).focus();
});
```